# Why is python giving an error when I play my second sound

Tags: python, audio, python-playsound

I used `from playsound import playsound` and I tried running these two sounds in the same folder as the python folder.

```
playsound('insert.mp3')
playsound('beep.mp3')
```

The first sound played, but when it got to the second one it said.

```
Error 263 for command:
        open beep.mp3
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.

    Error 263 for command:
        close beep.mp3
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
Failed to close the file: beep.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Name\Google Drive\Downloads\Jasosc\JasoPC.py", line 15, in <module>
    playsound('beep.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 72, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'open {}'.format(sound))
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand   
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 263 for command:
        open beep.mp3
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do

```
pip uninstall playsound
```

2. Then

```
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

3. Close your code editor, reopen and run

Comment: I have a question, what if I compile my program into an EXE and share it across the web will it still work because other computers may have a diff version not 1.2.2.

Comment: Other computers might not have this lib at all, so yes, it should work!

Comment: Do you know a way before any of my code runs, check to see if they have it?